# Showing route to a certain location on a MKMapView iOS?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm working on a app that involves a MKMapView, and I need to show a route from the User's current location to a certain location. I've played around with the MKMapView, and I can't find something that would show a route. Any ideas?!?

P.S., If I could also get help on finding out how far apart those two locations are, (User's Location and Certain Location), that would be even more awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the distance, you may use `CLLocation`:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

MapKit can give you directions using the `MKDirections` class. But that is only available for iOS 7 and higher. For older iOS version, you need an external framework/API to calculate the route for you, e.g. [Google Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

To display a route on the map, you would use Map Overlays (probably `MKPolyline` and `MKPolylineView`).

Answer (score 0):

Try it: https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes
Its work for me. But you must do some changes.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to automatically show a route in an MKMapView. There is support for it in iOS 7, but it's a toolkit of components, not a ready-made feature. It will take a fair amount of development. You will have to query the location manager for route information, then create an overlay layer with polylines based on the route information you get back. I haven't tried this, but I've read about it in the Xcode docs for iOS 7.

The simplest thing to do is to invoke the maps application to display the route for you. That only takes a few lines of code.